When zoomed out sprite does not get rendered, because it is between two pixels
I have generated a large Maze (500 x 500) in Unity and want to reder it.
I have a white rectangular sprite as a wall and render the top and left wall for each cell of the maze. For the cells at the right I render the right wall and for cells at the bottom I render the bottom wall to.
This works great on smaller mazes (like 100 x 100), but if I render bigger mazes some walls are not rendered.
maze Render
I think this is because as this scale the field of view is very large and somtimes a wall is between two pixels and does not get rendered.
If I zoom in on the big maze everything gets rendered.
How do I fix this?
Can I do something so if a wall is between two pixels it snaps to the closer pixel.
Or maybe I could draw the pixels of the wall directly. But how do I do that?

Could you not just increase the resolution of your game/scene view?

No It does make it a little bit bettet, but the gaps mostly remain

Try the 2D Pixel Perfect package provided by Unity.
Please note that rotations, as well as smooth movement, zooming and scaling, break pixel perfection in general. I didn't dive deep into the capabilities of this package. But just from briefly reading the description there are some built-in ways to handle that.
